# Using a function to add a column of cells that meet a certain criteria

Tags: excel, function, count, sum

I am having an issue with Excel trying to add multiple cells that meet certain criteria.

The file I am currently working with displays our entire inventory system. This includes the dates an item was listed and the total price the item is listed for.

My goal is to try and have three columns created. One column simply displays the month, the second column displays the quantity that is actively listed for the month, and the third column will add the total value of the product currently listed for the month.

I have already figured out the quantity formula using a countifs function, `=COUNTIFS('RANGE'!$Q$2:$Q$1007,">=1/1/23",'RANGE'!$Q$2:$Q$1007,"<=1/31/23")`

This is what I came up with so far, but I get a #VALUE! error.

```
=SUMIFS('RANGE'!L:L,'RANGE'!$Q$2:$Q$1007,">=1/1/23",'RANGE'!$Q$2:$Q$1007,"<=1/31/23")
```

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: The ranges passed to `SUMIFS` must be of an equal dimension. `'RANGE'!L:L` comprises 1,048,576 rows, `'RANGE'!$Q$2:$Q$1007` only 1,006.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ranges passed to `SUMIFS` must be of an equal dimension. `'RANGE'!L:L` comprises 1,048,576 rows, `'RANGE'!$Q$2:$Q$1007` only 1,006.